# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined......How to get a single post

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mern

```
import React,{useEffect, useState} from 'react'
//import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import { FcLikePlaceholder, FcComments } from "react-icons/fc";

const SinglePost = () => {
  const [data,setdata] = useState([])

  const callSinglePage = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch('/post/:id', {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",    
        },
        credentials: "include"
      });
            
      const data = await res.json();
      console.log(data);
      setdata(data.post);
    
      if(!res.status === 200){ 
        const error = new Error(res.error);
        throw error;
      }
    
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
    
  useEffect(()=>{
    callSinglePage();
  });

  return (
    <div className="bg">
    <h2>Confession</h2>
    <h5>Read Secrets</h5>
    <div>
      {
        data.map(post=>{
          return (
            <div className = "confession">
              <div className="post">
                <h3>{post.heading}</h3>
              </div>
              <div className="body-2">
                <p>{post.confess}</p>
              </div>
              <FcLikePlaceholder  size="2em"/>
              <FcComments style={{position:'relative',left:'20px'}}size="2em"/>
            </div>
          )
        })
      }
    </div>
  </div>
)}

export default SinglePost
```

App.js:

```
<Route path = '/post/:id'>
  {user ? <SinglePost/> : <Signup/>}
</Route>
```

```js
router.get('/post/:id',authenticate,async (req,res)=>{
  try {
    const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);
    res.status(200).json(post);
  } catch(err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
})
```

In postman, I'm getting the single post that means the backend is working fine.
Why is the map undefined?
I'm fetching write, and in URL also I'm writing http://localhost:3000/post/612a241ec1ac483f08e78c78
and the id is correct, but it's not working

ERROR:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

```
src/components/SinglePost.js:42
  39 | <div className="bg">
  40 | <h2>Confession</h2>
  41 | <h5>Read Secrets</h5>
> 42 | <div>
     | ^  43 |     {
  44 |         data.map(post=>{
  45 |             return(
View compiled
▶ 18 stack frames were collapsed.
callSinglePage
src/components/SinglePost.js:22
  19 |         
  20 |         const data = await res.json();
  21 |         console.log(data);
> 22 |         setdata(data.post);
     | ^  23 | 
  24 |         if(! res.status === 200){ 
  25 |             const error = new Error(res.error);
```

Plz, help.

Comment: What is the `console.log(data);` gives?

Comment: Does your request return an object (single item) or an array?

Comment: Why a SinglePost would return an array?

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the Id from the params .

```
const { id } = useParams();
```

The issue in your code is this `/post/:id` line inside your fetch . You need to replace the id with the id received from the url .

Once you have read the Id you need to pass to your fetch call as

```
fetch(`/post/${id}`)
```

Also if your data.post is an object then your code will fail again because you cannot do `.map` on an object . So when setting the state you need to do ([data.post])

Comment: thanks bro, it helped i upvoted ur and, it will show later bcz currently I do not have enough reputations to upvote, once again thanks